# Python replace '\0' in string with null

Tags: python, replace, null-terminated

I'm currently facing a strange problem. 
I want to replace the '\0' in strings with 'null' and read through many forums and always saw the same answer:

```
text_it = "request on port 21 that begins with many '\0' characters, 
preventing the affected router"
text_it.replace('\0', 'null')
```

or

```
text_it.replace('\x00', 'null')
```

When I now print the string, I get the following result:

```
"request on port 21 that begins with many '\0' characters, preventing the 
affected router"
```

Nothing happened.

So I used this method and it worked but it seems to be too much effort for such a small change:

```
text_it = text_it.split('\0')
text_it = text_it[0] + 'null' + text_it[1]
```

Any idea why the replace function didn't work?

Comment: `text_it = text_it.replace('\0', 'null')` ?

Comment: It worked to me

Comment: @Rakesh Of course! Sometimes I just don't see the obvious. Thanks!

Comment: @MelvinTomKlimke Don't forget to select your preferred answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one single line:

```
text_it = text_it.replace('\0', 'null').replace('\x00', 'null')
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, so they can not be modified through the `replace()` method. But this method returns the expected output, so you can assign this returned value to `text_it`. Here is the (simple) solution:

```
text_it = "request on port 21 that begins with many '\0' characters, preventing the affected router"
text_it = text_it.replace('\0', 'null')

print(text_it)
# request on port 21 that begins with many 'null' characters, preventing the affected router
```